# Error when using AWS-SDK-GO (NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've recently started using the [aws-sdk-go](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go) package. 
Walking through the instructions, my folder structure is as follows:

- bin/ , pkg/ (as always)
- src/

  - app/main.go (code taken from the [docs](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go#using))
  - github.com/aws

Now when I run `go install`, and then execute the app.exe (using windows here), 
I'm getting the following error:

```
panic: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to provide an AWS access key and secret key to authenticate and use AWS services.

See the README here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go#configuring-credentials

Comment: not only that, but in some cases you need to attach a role to the instance (mine had none) https://stackoverflow.com/a/45261421/647380

Comment: in general you should refrain from placing access/secret keys on ec2 hosts. use roles instead.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone runs into the same issue I had with this:

I read a doc that said to put the file at `%USERPROFILE%.awscredentials` on a Windows, but they just forgot the slash. It should be `%USERPROFILE%.aws/credentials`.

Answer (score 1):

Double check the format of your `~/.aws/credential` file.

In my case, the credentials used the following format :

```
[profile]
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxx
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yyyy
```

changing it to the following fixed the issue :

```
[profile]
aws_access_key_id = xxxx
aws_secret_access_key = yyyy
```

Comment: This helped us there was an interesting thing where the caps version worked for python based aws cli, but failed for go based sops cli. (theory is that maybe python AWS SDK is case insensitive, but go AWS SDK is case sensitive for the config file)